# Rectangle at the bottom of the activity

Tags: java, android, tabs

[image]

Trying to study Android Studio. How can I create bottom rectangle with "Log in" text? And silly question about tabs. Is that correct, that I move them with marginTop property?

Comment: you can create a `LinearLayout` with the `textview` using `gravity Left` property on the `TextView` element

Comment: use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to keep the layout at the bottom

Comment: Thanks! But exactly to draw rectangle? Drawable?

Comment: Thank you @Aspicas! I think that's the key!

Comment: @VladislavDmitriev check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that `Layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.90">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:background="#ffFF9800"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LOG IN >"
                android:id="@+id/textView76"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @Aspicas! It's at the bottom, but seems something went wrong https://pp.vk.me/c636924/v636924257/1398e/K2_XcDPPPeQ.jpg . Or thats what we want? Sorry :(

Comment: @VladislavDmitriev Sorry... Whats the problem? Color? I can't see any problem